# Call a method whose name is contained within a string?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn a string into a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317298/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-method-call)

Using Ruby 1.9, how does one call a method which is contained within a string.  I have attempted the following:

```
self.'method_name'
```

Basically what I am attempting to do is call methods based on a common naming convention building on the current methods name.  I would like to be be able to call

```
self."#{__method__}_path"
```

and give I am in method `search` have the code execute as if I was calling

```
self.search_path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `send`?

Something like:

```
ACTIONS = %w[foo bar]

def execute(action)
      return send("do_#{action}") if ACTIONS.include?(action)
      raise "Unexpected action"
end
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send